# How to say: When are we meeting?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

How would I say "When are we meeting?" in the context of asking a friend who I am planning to see e.g. tonight.

This should be really easy but I can't seem to find a way that sounds 'French'.

I tried things like:

- Quand nous nous rencontrerons?
- Quand nous réunirons-nous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural way to say it could be:

> Quand est-ce qu'on se retrouve?

This is more informal but probably suited to the context if you're asking this to a friend.

Comment: merci beaucoup!

Comment: This is not that informal. An informal version would be "On se retrouve quand?" Of course there is more formal, as in "Quand se retrouve-t-on?", but none ever says that.

Answer (score 4):

Even more informally than Dahlai's suggestions :

On se revoit quand ?

... sounds more living, native (spoken) French to me.

Comment: even "*On se voit quand ?*"

Comment: Indeed, or «Quand est-ce qu'on se voit ?», or else «Quand se (re)voit-on?». It appears the key to making this "sound French", as the original question put it, is in the choice of the verb  "se voir" : to meet (or "se revoir" : meet again) and also the "indefinite pronoun" : «on» rather than «nous».

Comment: "se retrouver" doesn't sound like spoken French. It can be used for example if you are texting: "On se retrouve à 10h ?" but becomes weird when spoken.